# Override the value of two variables in the "Theme My Login" WordPress plugin so I cam stop multiple email notifications to admin/user

Tags: wordpress

I have seen this code in the **Theme My Login** plugin for WordPress:

```
/**
 * Filters whether to send the new user notification or not.
 *
 * @since 7.0.7
 *
 * @param bool $send_user_notification Whether to send the new user notification or not.
 */
$send_user_notification = (bool) apply_filters( 'tml_send_new_user_notification', true );

/**
 * Filters whether to send the new user admin notification or not.
 *
 * @since 7.0.7
 *
 * @param bool $send_admin_notification Whether to send the new user admin notification or not.
 */
$send_admin_notification = (bool) apply_filters( 'tml_send_new_user_admin_notification', true );
```

Is there any way that I can init these two variables via my child theme functions.php so that they return `false`? I have another plugin **WP Approve User** which also sends new user notifications and I am now getting **two emails** for each user (and admin).

The way I understand it, if I could override these two variables as `false` it would stop sending email notifications.

Unless there is another solution.

---

So, looking a bit more at what **Theme My Login** plugin does:

```
add_action( 'register_new_user', 'tml_set_new_user_password' );
add_action( 'register_new_user', 'tml_handle_auto_login'     );

add_action( 'register_new_user',      'tml_send_new_user_notifications', 10, 1 );
add_action( 'edit_user_created_user', 'tml_send_new_user_notifications', 10, 2 );

remove_action( 'register_new_user',      'wp_send_new_user_notifications' );
remove_action( 'edit_user_created_user', 'wp_send_new_user_notifications' );
```

And in **WP Approve User**:

```
public function register_new_user( $user_id ) {
    if ( ! get_user_meta( $user_id, 'wp-approve-user', true ) ) {
        remove_action( 'register_new_user', 'wp_send_new_user_notifications' );
        add_action( 'register_new_user', 'wp_new_user_notification' );
    }
}
```

That is all I have found. getting in a pickle here! I would like the email notifications to work right for the user.

Interestingly I can't actually find `tml_send_new_user_notification` action any where in the **Theme My Login** code so I might be completely barking up the wrong tree here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add the following to my `functions.php` file in my child theme:

```
// ==============================================================
// Switch off Theme My Login notifications because WP Approve User manages it
add_filter( 'tml_send_new_user_notification', '__return_false' );
add_filter( 'tml_send_new_user_admin_notification', '__return_false' );
// ==============================================================
```

This code adds the required returns and returns `false`. Thus the **Theme My Login** plugin no longer sends the notifications. **WP Approve User** can take over.